# Files with macros compilation without loading a file in sbcl (common lisp)

Tags: macros, compilation, common-lisp, sbcl

I have a file with some lisp code and I want to compile it to fasl. I'm defining some functions and macros that use some of that functions and more functions that use these macros.

So when I tried to compile the file with

```
$ sblc --eval "(compile-file \"file.lisp\")" --eval "(quit)"
```

I got compilation errors about that the macro couldn't expand because the function is not defined. But everything has been compiling in the normal order:

```
; compiling (DEFUN MY-FUNCTION ...)
; compiling (DEFMACRO MY-MACRO-THAT-USES-MY-FUNCTION ...)
; compiling (DEFUN OTHER-FUNCTION-THAT-USES-MACRO ...)
; file: /path/to/file/file.lisp
; in: DEFUN OTHER-MY-FUNCTION-THAT-USES-MACRO
;     (MY-MACRO-THAT-USES-MY-FUNCTION 1)
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   during macroexpansion of (MY-MACRO-THAT-USES-MY-FUNCTION 1). Use *BREAK-ON-SIGNALS* to
;   intercept.
;    The function COMMON-LISP-USER::MY-FUNCTION is undefined.
```

So then I tried to load the file first and then to compile it:

```
sbcl --eval "(load \"file.lisp\")" --eval "(compile-file \"file.lisp\")" --eval "(quit)"
```

And this worked without warning or errors.

But this solution looks ugly because of:

1) I need to specify the file twice (even if I write the bash script, this doesn't look so good)

2) It looks like the file is compiled twice: first time when I load it and second time when I actually compile it.

3) If I'll do it from `repl`, the file will be loaded to it and sometimes this can be bad. What if I just want to compile the file, but not load it?

So I see 3 variant here:

1) I'm doing something completely wrong.

2) I need to regroup macros and functions several files and load only necessary function with `load` but not the whole file. (this doesn't help with any of the problems but make them less significant)

3) There is a command that does does what I want to do and I just couldn't find it.

So how should I compile such type of files?
Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a frequent question. Probably already answered on Stackoverflow.

- during compilation, the code of functions is generated, but not loaded into the compiler.
- macros OTOH are also made available in the compile-time environment

Two solutions:

- separate files: one which defines macros and the needed functions, another one where the macros are being used. Load the macro and its support code, before compiling dependent files.
- use `EVAL-WHEN` with `:load-toplevel`, `:compile-toplevel` and `:execute` around the functions which are needed at compile-time. `:compile-toplevel` makes sure than any enclosed top-level code gets executed during compilation - for a `defun` this would define the function at compile-time, too.

See: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_eval_w.htm#eval-when

Note, that you don't need two evals in your example. You can also write `--eval "(progn (load ...) (compile-file ...))` or even `--eval "(let ((file ...)) (load file) (compile-file file))`.